# How to iterate through collections, docs and subcollection in FirebaseFirestore, Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I need to get all the IDs of the docs from date (22, 25, 26, 27, ....)

dailyWinner/2021-05/26 >>> all docs IDs

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queries in Firestore are shallow, meaning that when you fetch a document you don't get back the data contained in any of the linked subcollections.

So you need to get the list of subcollections for the `2021-05` document and for each subcollection, query all the document it contains.

The difficulty you will encounter is that "[retrieving a list of collections is not possible with the mobile/web client libraries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#list_subcollections_of_a_document)" (including the Flutter plugin).

You will find in this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-list-all-subcollections-of-a-cloud-firestore-document-17f2bb80a166) two methods for listing the subcollections of a document (i.e. save the list of collections IDs in the parent document or use a [Callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/functions/usage)). Once you have the subcollection IDs, you need to query each subcollection, like:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('dailyWinners/2021-05/22')
    .get()
    .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
            // ...
        });
    });
```

Comment: Here I need to change the dates and get data for all dates

Comment: "Here I need to change the dates and get data for all dates" => Not sure to understand what you exactly mean. But it is also possible to duplicate the documents in one global collection, with e.g. a Cloud Function. It all depends on your exact use case, the number of subcollections and cos, how frequently you query them, etc...